# How Domain maps map indexes to target locales array in multi-dimension case

Tags: chapel

I didn't find how the domain map maps the indices in the multi-dimensional domains to the multi-dimensional target locales.

1.) How the target locales (one dimension) is arranged in multi-dimension fashion which equals the distribution dimension to map the indexes?

2.) In documentation it states that for multi-dimension case, the computation should be done in every dimension. For the domain `{1..8, 1..8}` ==> dom
assume `dom` is block-distributed over 6 target locales.

Steps in mapping

1 for 1st dimension (1..8) do the computation
if `idx` is `low<=idx<=high` then `locid` is
`floor (idx-low)*N / (high-low+1)` gives me an index say `i`.

Repeat the same for 2nd dimension which gives me an index say `j`.
Now I have a tuple `( i, j )` 
how this is mapped to the target locales array of dimension 2?

What the domain map do for changing the 1D target locales array to distribution dimension?

Is something like reshape function ?

Please let me know if this lacks sufficient information.

Comment: Would you mind to point out in which part of [ http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/dists/BlockDist.html?highlight=block#module-BlockDist ] this you try to get a clarified explanation of the Chapel-mapping processes? Thank you.

Comment: I had a look at block dist module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific details about how a domain's indices are mapped to a program's locales are not defined by the Chapel language itself, but rather by the implementation of the domain map used to declare the domain.  In the comments under your question, you mention that you're referring to the `Block` distribution, so I'll focus on that in my answer ([documented here](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/dists/BlockDist.html)), but note that any other domain map could take a different approach.

The `Block` distribution takes an optional `targetLocales` argument which permits you to specify the set of locales to be targeted, as well as their virtual topology.  For instance, if I declare and populate a few arrays of locales:

```
var grid1: [1..3, 1..2] locale,   // a 3 x 2 array of locales
    grid2: [1..2, 1..3] locale;   // a 2 x 3 array of locales

for i in 1..3 {
  for j in 1..2 {
    grid1[i,j] = Locales[(2*(i-1) + j-1)%numLocales];
    grid2[j,i] = Locales[(3*(j-1) + i-1)%numLocales];
  }
}
```

I can then pass them in as the `targetLocales` arguments to a few instances of a `Block`-distributed domain:

```
use BlockDist;

config const n = 8;

const D = {1..n, 1..n},
      D1 = D dmapped Block(D, targetLocales=grid1),
      D2 = D dmapped Block(D, targetLocales=grid2);
```

Each domain will distribute its `n` rows to the first dimension of its `targetLocales` grid and its `n` columns to the second dimension.  We can see the results of this distribution by declaring arrays of integers over these domains and assigning them in parallel to make each element store its owning locale's ID, as follows:

```
var A1: [D1] int,
    A2: [D2] int;

forall a in A1 do
  a = here.id;

forall a in A2 do
  a = here.id;

writeln(A1, "\n");
writeln(A2, "\n");
```

When running on six or more locales (`./a.out -nl 6`), the output is as follows, revealing the underlying grid structure:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5

0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2
3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5
3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5
3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5
3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5
```

For a 1-dimensional `targetLocales` array, the documentation says:

> If the rank of `targetLocales` is `1`, a greedy heuristic is used to reshape the array of target locales so that it matches the rank of the distribution and each dimension contains an approximately equal number of indices.

For example, if we distribute to a 1-dimensional 4-element array of locales:

```
var grid3: [1..4] locale;

for i in 1..4 do
  grid3[i] = Locales[(i-1)%numLocales];

var D3 = D dmapped Block(D, targetLocales=grid3);

var A3: [D3] int;

forall a in A3 do
  a = here.id;

writeln(A3);
```

we can see that the target locales form a square, as expected:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

The documentation is intentionally vague about how a 1D `targetLocales` argument will be reshaped if it's not a perfect square, but we can find out what's done in practice by using the [`targetLocales()` query](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html?highlight=targetlocales#ChapelArray.targetLocales) on the domain.  Also, note that if no `targetLocales` array is supplied, the entire `Locales` array (which is 1D) is used by default.  As an illustration of both these things, if the following code is run on six locales:

```
var D0 = D dmapped Block(D);

writeln(D0.targetLocales());
```

we get:

```
LOCALE0 LOCALE1
LOCALE2 LOCALE3
LOCALE4 LOCALE5
```

illustrating that the current heuristic matches our explicit `grid1` declaration above.